# My question is about factor covariance in CFA

Tags: confirmatory-factor

I did a CFA for a scale with 4 factors. the model is fitted( RMSEA, CFI, GFI...)
But some factors covariance is very low and also χ2/df is significant.Is it a problem?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. Could you provide more information about the analysis? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. Without further information, this question remains unclear.

Comment: My research was: Evaluation of factor structure of  the tolerance scale in marital context. This scale has 4 factors and 24 items. i used Amos20 for evaluation structure . four factor model had a good fitness(RMSEA= .92, cfi= .91,Agfi=.90,.....)

Comment: Please edit the question instead of commenting.